# Using mmap with pwrite together

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

Assume a C/C++ Linux application that have a log file of a fixed size and two threads that operate this log file: `Producer` and `Consumer`. `Producer` thread produces large portions of data that must be persisted in a log file as a contiguous block. `Consumer` thread reads the data randomly from that log file (until the data from the log file is moved to some long-term storage).

I want to use `pwrite` and `fsync` to write data to the log by `Producer` thread, because, according to numerous sources, this is quite common practice for keeping the log. But the same time I want to make `Consumer` thread read the log file through `mmap`, because the data is read randomly and I want to speed up reads through `madvise`.

The question is: does the operating system (Linux, OS X or any other POSIX compliant OS) provide guarantees, that if the page is currently loaded to memory from `mmap`'ed file, it would be automatically updated or at least invalidated when the `Producer` thread updates the corresponding block in a log file through `pwrite`? If not, what should I do to let the `Consumer` thread see the updated data immediately after update?

Comment: Why don't you just use mmap for both? If this really is threads (in the same address space), you can share the mapping between the two also.

Comment: Do you mean the `Producer` thread must use memory mapping when writing file? From my point of view, using `pwrite` has several advantages: 1) write of large contiguous block requires just one seek of HDD track when using `pwrite`; 2) such operation won't lead to page fault. Please let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: You would be correct about no page fault. `pwrite` is going to go into the cache, however. It does not necessarily go straight to disk. mmapped pages are basically interacting with the cache directly, avoiding an extra copy of the data from your memory to the cache.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how does the caching work on low level, so a couple of questions then: 1) what if I open the file with `O_DIRECT` flag? Man pages say that it helps to avoid caching during writes, while nothing prevent me from `mmap`'ing this file; 2) is the operating system smart enough to perform as few as possible seeks of HDD tracks when I write large portion of data through `mmap` followed by `msync`?